# Firebase Phone Number Authentification IOS Error: Optional("Token mismatch")

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi I have follow the tutorial for the phone number auth in swift , this is my code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class SignInViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var number: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let myColor : UIColor = UIColor.white
    number.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    number.layer.borderColor = myColor.cgColor
    number.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
    number.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string :"Enter your number", attributes : [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white] )

}

@IBAction func sendCode(_ sender: Any){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Phone Number", message: "Is this your phone number? \n \(number.text!)", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) {(UIAlertAction) in
        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(self.number.text!){ (verificationID, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            }else {

                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                defaults.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVID")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "code", sender: Any?.self)

            }

        }

    }

    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    alert.addAction(cancel)
    self.present(alert,animated : true, completion : nil)


}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

and for the verification this code :

```
      import UIKit
      import FirebaseAuth

      class VerificationCodeViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var code: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myColor : UIColor = UIColor.white
    code.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    code.layer.borderColor = myColor.cgColor
    code.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
    code.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string :"Enter  your verification code", attributes : [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white] )

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func verifyCode(_ sender: Any) {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let credential : PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: defaults.string(forKey: "authVID")!, verificationCode: code.text!)

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user,error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            }else{

            print("Phone number: \(String(describing: user?.phoneNumber))")
            let userInfo = user?.providerData[0]
            print("Provider ID: \(String(describing: userInfo?.providerID))")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logged", sender: Any?.self)
        }
    }
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

I run my app I enter the number but i get this error Error:

> Optional("Token mismatch")

Thanks you for help

Comment: I am gatting same error, can you get solution for that problem??

Answer (score 6):

Please have in mind, about the type of certificate you are using while sharing the build,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {


// If you are using the development certificate you have to use this,
    Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.prod)

// If you are using distribution certificate you should use this
    Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.sandbox)

// If you want Firebase to automatically detect the type use this.
    Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)

}
```

This is important because while sending push notification the URL changes in the server side.

> SANDBOX_ENDPOINT_URL =
>   'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195'; const
>   SERVICE_ENDPOINT_URL = 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195';

I believe the token type will be used to choose the URL of APNS.

Comment: If you are using the development certificate you have to use .sandbox, please correct this

Comment: @SaadBilal why is it that for the development certificate you have to use `.sandbox` and not `.prod`

Comment: @LanceSamaria because your env is dev, and sandbox is for dev/testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a reference to the database. The error is saying that the service account is not recognizing the phone number. When you're registering a user with a phone number, you need to be updating the database.

```
let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://MyFireBaseProject.com/")
```

Your database URL can be found in the database console.